# jQPlot force static minimum and maximum values on y-axis

Tags: jquery, user-interface, graph, jqplot

I am using [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) to render bar charts and am looking to do something fairly straightforward but I am not sure if the library has an option for this.

I have graphs like this one, where the maximum possible value on the y-axis can be 42.

[image]

Let's say if for one case, my highest value for any of the bars is 14, then the graph will be rendered to show only up to 14.

[image]

However, I want it so that, IN ALL CASES, I can see that upper threshold of 42 rendered.

This is what I have for now:

```
var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [line1], {
            animate: true,
            animateReplot: true, 
            seriesDefaults: {renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer},
            series:[{
              pointLabels:{
                  show: true,
                  labels:[depression, anxiety, stress]
              },
              rendererOptions: {
                  animation: {
                    speed: 3500
                  },
                  barWidth: 50,
                  barPadding: -15,
                  barMargin: 0,
                  varyBarColor : true,
                  highlightMouseOver: false
              }
            }],
            axes: {
              xaxis: {
                  renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
              }
            },
            canvasOverlay: {
              show: true,
              objects: [{
                  horizontalLine: {
                      y: 42,
                      lineWidth: 3,
                      color: 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      shadow: true,
                      xOffset: 0
                  }
              }]
            }
          });
        plot3.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add this to your `axes:`

```
       axes: {
            xaxis: {           
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer                   
            },
            yaxis: {
                min:0,
                max:42
            }
        },
```

you can add `tickInterval` to specify the interval between the ticks on `yaxis`

Please add these setting to your `replot` function as you are trying to reset the axis:

```
     plot3.replot({axes: {
                xaxis: {           
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer                       
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min:0,
                    max:42
                }
            }});
```

OR

You can say

```
plot3.replot(false);
```

so it will not reset your axes.

Comment: copied your code (every within `$.jqplot({});`. Still doesn't work. What version are you using?

Comment: version of what??  can you create a jsfiddle for your code... let me see what you are trying to do....

Comment: its not working for you because on `replot` you resetting your axes...
Please specify my code inside your replot call also.

Comment: I will test this out and let you know