# varying colors for fill using fillbetween for jQplot based on which line has highest value

Tags: javascript, jqplot, fill

As per
http://www.jqplot.com/examples/fillBetweenLines.php
, is it possible to alter the fillbetween - color based on which line series has the highest value?
I am trying to emulate the ["Created VS Resolved"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-created-vs-resolved-gadget-720416880.html) - chart from Jira, which shows red fill for the periods where the red line is over the green, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your desired color afterwards by using one of the following options:

A) Do a replot

```
var chart = $.jqplot('chartContainer', data, chartOptions);
chart.replot({
    fillBetween: {
        color: '#00FF00'
    }
});
```

Another example for using replot to alter the chart options can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928868/jqplot-force-static-minimum-and-maximum-values-on-y-axis/17930551#17930551)

B) Use the themeEngine

```
var theme = {
    fillBetween: {
        color: '#00FF00'
    }
};
```

the documentation provides an example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/theming.html#)

This however allows only to change the color of the complete filling. switching from one color to another within the same chart is not provided by jqplot.

The `jquery.jqplot.js` draws the filling in the function `jqPlot.prototype.doFillBetweenLines` (in version 1.0.9 it's around line 3203). I think it's possible to change the generation og the shape and color there.